# Updating the table with new value by finding specific row

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that I add information depending on the order number.
So when I enter information, I add some column names as numbers.
Then update the rows with new values.

My table takes 3 values everytime I insert value.

```
order number| total left |  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  | 5 |  6 |  7  | 8 |  9| 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
11          | 100        |  a  |  b  |  c  |  d  | e |  f |  0  |   |   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
12          | 10         |  x |   y  |   z |  0  |   |    |  s  | d |  f|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I try to add new column, the value of the new rows in every other value becomes null or 0 depending on if it is int or varchar.

When I insert 3 values to order number 12, I want the last 0 in that row to be updated.

(In this case, **4-5-6** but I get **7-8-9** updated.)

So what is the best way for finding the last row which is 0 
(in this case *column 4* for *order number 12* and insert the new values of s,d,f to the 4-5-6 instead of 7-8-9 ?

So maybe something like:

> Loop through rows, find 0, insert 3 rows, break.

I take the last column:

```
    $NewColumnNameKoliAdet=$LastColumnName+1;
    $NewColumnNameMusteri=$LastColumnName+2;
    $NewColumnNameTarih=$LastColumnName+3;
```

Then I add columns and update the table.

```
    $Query="ALTER TABLE `koli_stok_hareketleri`
    ADD `$NewColumnNameKoliAdet` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `$LastColumnName`,
    ADD `$NewColumnNameMusteri` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL AFTER `$NewColumnNameKoliAdet`,
    ADD `$NewColumnNameTarih` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL AFTER `$NewColumnNameMusteri`;";

 $Query="UPDATE koli_stok_hareketleri SET kalan_koli=kalan_koli- 
 '$Uretilen_Koli', 
 `$NewColumnNameKoliAdet` = '$Uretilen_Koli',
 `$NewColumnNameMusteri` = '$Musteri_ismifromrow',
 `$NewColumnNameTarih` = '$Now' 
  WHERE koli_ismi ='$Koli_IsmifromRow' AND 
  koli_parti_no='$Parti_NofromRow'";
```

So the problem is it adds three value to each row automatically and but when I update, I need to update the order number 12 from 4th column not 7.

Comment: What is your sql? pls. provide that. And do you try to alter the table structure or insert values?
Pls. also try to structure your question. I don't get what you try to do and what you tried so far ... What is the main Question? Pls. Update.

Comment: Hi Helle, 
I have updated some information. Thank you !

Comment: Can you describe what the purpose of that idea is? I have a feeling you're running in a wrong direction. Why are you altering the DB? The DB should remain static most of the time ...
Pls. try to provide an example of what your input is, what your output expactation is and what really happens ... it is so not clear what you try to do.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of appallingly poor schema design. Stop. See normalisation.

Comment: Yes ! I guess I should change the way I design my table :) Normalization would work.

Comment: I have a feeling all these extra columns actually ought to be rows in a child table. Normalisation , as mentioned above.